# Is Naruto's most proficient move still Shadow Clones?

Tags: naruto

After becoming Hokage, and so much more in ''Boruto'', it is safe to say that Naruto has learned a great deal more than when he was just a kid, and originally learned to use the Shadow Clone jutsu. He has been using it frequently since then, using it whilst fighting to pull off his Rasengan or to multi-task in his daily life. Obviously it is not his most destructive jutsu, but talking sheer mastery with it, I doubt he would be better at another jutsu.

But with how many jutsus and techniques Naruto has by now, is his Shadow Clone jutsu still the one he's the most **proficient** at? If not, then what *is* his most proficient jutsu, and when did it become his most proficient?

Comment: I would say that his most broken jutsu would be the Sage art: Super Tailed Beast Rasenshuriken. It is a giant Rasenshuriken with six paths sage chakra and chakra from Kurama and all the other tailed beasts. The shadow clone jutsu is good but since it divides the chakra evenly among how many clones there are then the more clones you have the weaker they are going to be.

Answer (score 1):

I think his strongest justu is Sage Art: Super Tailed Beast Rasenshuriken, but his most PROFICIENT jutsu would be multi shadow clone justu simply because it is an extension of his shadow clone jutsu, which is one of the first jutsu he mastered and he has been using it since he was 12 or however old he was when he defended Iruka.

Answer (score 0):

On a battlefield Rasengan and Rasenshuriken variations is problably the most proficient, we can realize that looking to how often it was used on battle and its damage, since Kakuzu's battle against Naruto , he was looking forward to improve that technique

On a more general porpuse problably Shadow Clone jutsu wich he uses to initiate battle's as to accomplish dayly stuff

In my opinion, Shadow Clone Jutsu is the most proficient one in general, it allows naruto buy time to think and is pretty amazing all the ways that he combine more destructive jutsus to it

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is still his most proficient jutsu as he is using it all the time even at the village so as to keep up with the workload and help many. He is constantly maintaining kage bunshin. Therefore with so much usage, it will be his most proficient. This is also shown by the fact that he can maintain a large number of them for a long period of time.

However, in a battle situation, this is not very useful. So he will use his next most proficient (almost equally proficient) Rasengan and varients of it. For example, in the fight with Delta, he used a multitude of Rasengans and a lot less clones. He usually hit anyone with a rasengan if he can get close enough. He almost uses it as much as he uses plain punches.